# Angular component communication parent - child not working

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular-components

I have a problem with the communication between parent - child component.
I have a list of multiple items which I want to put in a child component, but on one off the other reason he will not fill the child object and gives an undefined. The parent object is aware of the amount of items, so this is initialized correctly and also with debugging the objects are filled. but in the child an undefined to fill every card where I want to place objectdata in.

Let's see the code :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,    
    LayoutModule    
  ],
  declarations: [    
    AppComponent,    
    PortalcardComponent,
    PortalcardsComponent,    
    ErrorPageComponent 
  ],  
  providers: [AuthGuardService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is is about the portalcarccomponent, and the portalcardscomponents in app.module.ts

```
<app-portalcards>        
</app-portalcards>
```

this is the tag in app.component.html

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { PortalCardData } from '../../../core/interfaces/portalcard'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-portalcards',
  templateUrl: './portalcards.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./portalcards.component.scss']
})
export class PortalcardsComponent {
  portalcards = PortalCardData;  
}
```

portalcards.component.ts

```
<app-portalcard *ngFor="let portalcard of portalcards">      
    [portalcard]="portalcard"
</app-portalcard>
```

portalcard.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PortalCard } from '../../interfaces/portalcard'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-portalcard',
  templateUrl: './portalcard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portalcard.component.scss']
})
export class PortalcardComponent{
  @Input() portalcard: PortalCard  
}
```

portalcard.component.html

```
<div class="card">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{portalcard.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{portalcard.subtitle}}</p>
    <a href="" (click)="false" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">{{portalcard.button.title}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It has to be probably something small, but I don't see it :(. Maybe somebody can help me out here.

Thx . Regards Marc

These are the errors in google developer toolbar. 2 items. 2 errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdJQN.png)

Comment: According to this source - https://angular.io/api/core/Input, Input parameters should be sent as DOM Properties, so you have to send your `[portalcard]="portalcard"` as a parameter, near that ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<app-portalcard *ngFor="let portalcard of portalcards" [portalcard]="portalcard">          
</app-portalcard>
```

Instead of your code:

```
<app-portalcard *ngFor="let portalcard of portalcards">      
    [portalcard]="portalcard"
</app-portalcard>
```

Comment: Thank you Peter and Belle (what was partly correct) ... This works as a charm

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `portalcards = PortalCardData` is of type singular instead of an array. It should be first define as an array so it can be iterated over with `*ngFor`.

You can try changing it to this
`portalcards = PortalCardData[]`

and to insert the input correctly with this

```
<app-portalcard *ngFor="let portalcard of portalcards" [portalcard]="portalcard">      
</app-portalcard>
```